# Include event when passing parameter array to a function using apply

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, apply

I'm using apply to pass an array of parameters to a function with an event listener, but I also need to pass the event since the function expects it. How do I include it? Can I put it into the array?

```
var myelement = document.getElementById('myElement');

myelement.addEventListener("click", function(){myfunction.apply(null, array)});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new array consisting of the event object (the first argument to the event handler function) and the contents of the array you care about.

```
apply( null, [ arguments[0] ].concat(array) )
```